# No camera preview

Tags: camera, linux, raspicam, picamera, raspberry-pi-os

I have a problem, when I write the command "raspistill -o desktop/image.jpg" in the terminal there is no output. How can I solve this problem is urgent... and btw the Geany programming editor is not compiling my files.

Comment: what research have you done to find a solution? ... why are you mentioning Geany?

Comment: Have you enabled the camera?

Comment: if "there is no output" - assuming you mean no output to the terminal - that would mean no errors, and the file would be created